# Android NDK linking shared library

Tags: android-ndk, dynamic-linking

I am currently trying to link 3 prebuilt shared libraries to a native JNI shared library. The shared libraries were built on linux. When I link one of the libraries to native JNI i got an unsatisfactory link error, attached below.

```
  Loading the library normally failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found.
```

the runtime dependency of my shared library (libdivsufsort) is shown below

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x9e00 contains 25 entries:
Tag        Type                         Name/Value
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname [libdivsufsort.so.3]
0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x8b8
0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x85c8
0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x209de8
0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x209df0
0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x1f0
0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x510
0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x258
0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              375 (bytes)
0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x20a000
0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           216 (bytes)
0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x7e0
0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x708
0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             216 (bytes)
0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x6c8
0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x688
0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          3
0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

Similar problems occur to my other libraries. The linkage works fine on linux cuz libc.so.6 is in library path.
It seems android does not support dynamic linking with versioned library, nor does it contain versioned libraries in system/lib. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You probably have a bigger problem than the versioned library dependency. If the library was prebuilt or LInux, it expects the Linux variant of **libc** which is not compatible with the Android (a.k.a. bionic) variant of **libc**. You should rebuild all your libraries with Android NDK toolchain.

Comment: you are right, i tried to used a ndk-built shared library on linux, and the system cannot find libc.so and libm.so.

Comment: if this is the case, how can prebuilt library be used in ndk? since these libraries should all be using libc.so.6(linux)

Comment: No you can't use this prebuilt library on Android. You need an Android flavor of the library.

Comment: Yeah what Alex said. You gotta cross compile using the android NDK toolchain. The NDK (favorably llvm) in NDK sources/cxx-stl contains the STL shared and static libraries for the specific android architecture you are trying to compile (arm, arm64, ...).